# Android - Installing pfx certificate at device level and accessing it programatically

Tags: android, pfx, java-websocket

I have a pfx file that I could install in my Android device. I want to create a secured Web Socket server, running on Android device, that should use certificate information I have just installed.

My requirement is that I do not want to bundle the pfx file with the apk.

Assume it to be a IOT solution where each device can have there own pfx file, so from the code perspective I am not tying up to a specific pfx file.